# comparing string without using jmp in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

kinda hard to exploain but I basically want to compare two strings and execute code without jumping to another function. for example below is what works but I don't want it, since it calls `len` and `got` function:

```
len:
    cmp byte [rsi+rdx], 0x0a
    jz got
    inc rdx
    jmp len
got:
    mov rax, 1
    syscall
```

So is there a way to execute `got` function code, if the the strings are equal without calling the function it self and otherwise execute the other piece of code?

FYI, the problem I have is that as you know `jmp` stores the `got` function location address which is picked randomly and I wouldn't be able to know it without debugging the assembly.

Comment: The only way without calling a function would be using the legacy [`CMPS`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmps:cmpsb:cmpsw:cmpsd:cmpsq) instruction. Search on SO for its usage.

Comment: @zx485: you can put a loop in *this* function instead of jumping to another one.  You only need `repe cmpsb` if you want it to be truly branchless (and slow).  So yes, you can execute the code of `got` by inlining it manually.

Comment: *jmp stores the got function location address*  Is this for code-injection or JIT?  If not, the linker takes care of this for you, and `jmp rel32` is fine as part of a position-independent executable.  Choosing a random base address for the whole block of code including the `jmp` and the target doesn't break it.  Relative branches enable position-independent code without relocation fixups.

Comment: Note that this will typically be assembled using relative jumps, so you actually don't need to know the absolute address of the labels `got` and `len`, only their relative offsets from the jump instruction.